# How to retrieve value from etc/sysconfig in Python

Tags: python, linux, bash, environment-variables, ini

I have a config file FOO in /etc/sysconfig/. This Linux file is very similar to INI-File, but without a section declaration.

In order to retrieve a value from this file, I used to write a shell script like:

```
source /etc/sysconfig/FOO
echo $MY_VALUE
```

Now I want to do the same thing in python. I tried to use ConfigParser, but ConfigParser does not accept such an INI-File similar format, unless it has a section declaration.

Is there any way to retrieve value from such a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could do exactly what you're doing with your shell script using the `subprocess` module and reading it's output. Use it with the `shell` option set to `True`.

Comment: i finally use commands.getstatusoutput("source /etc/sysconfig/FOO;echo $BAR") to get values

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `ConfigParser`, you could do something like:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.6

from StringIO import StringIO
import ConfigParser

def read_configfile_without_sectiondeclaration(filename):
    buffer = StringIO()
    buffer.write("[main]\n")
    buffer.write(open(filename).read())
    buffer.seek(0)
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.readfp(buffer)
    return config

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    config = read_configfile_without_sectiondeclaration(sys.argv[1])
    print config.items("main")
```

The code creates an in-memory filelike object containing a [main] section header and the contents of the specified file. ConfigParser then reads that filelike object.

Comment: ConfigParser has some problems. (1) All keys will be converted to lowercase. (2) The "" around a string value will not be removed. So finally I use another solution.

Comment: Have a look at the ConfigObj library. Might be it handles the problems you mention. http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html